# Are there any browser usage stats for the visually impaired?

Tags: statistics

I've done a lot of work optimizing websites for IE 6 high contrast mode and increased font sizes, with the intention of improving the experience for the visually impaired. However, it seems to me that anyone who is visually impaired would be more vigilant in upgrading because of the improved zoom features offered by advanced browsers. Are there any browser statistics available **specifically for visually impaired users?**

Comment: related http://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/57340/percentage-of-screen-readers-users-in-usa

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not *specifically* for visually impaired users, but the [WebAIM Survey of Preferences of Screen Readers Users](http://www.webaim.org/projects/screenreadersurvey/) is based on data from **predominantly** visually impaired users.

See the graphic on Disabilities Reported.  It states that 80% of respondents were blind, and another 16% had low vision/visual impairment.